# Filter out multiple names with the same ID - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks

I have a table in which a couple of the IDs have different values in the name column.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 |
| 2 | name_2 |
| 3 | name_3 |
| 4 | name_4 |
| 1 | other_name_1 |
| 2 | other_name_2 |
| 5 | name_5 |

I want to treat 'other_name_1' and 'other_name_2' as duplicates. I want to select every ID and Name from the table without the duplicates.

The desired output would be:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 |
| 2 | name_2 |
| 3 | name_3 |
| 4 | name_4 |
| 5 | name_5 |

Comment: How do you know it's "other_name_1" that is the duplicate?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter which name is the duplicate. I just want to have a single name for a single ID.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

```
select ID, min(Name)
from table
group by ID
```

since **min()** can be used with strings as well. This will give you the name to each ID that would be the first search order.